# Software center won't launch

Tags: software-center

So software centre will not open at all and whenever I try it usually crashes my system. So I used the terminal to open it using the command:

```
software-center
```

It came up with this

```
2015-06-27 20:53:22,642 - softwarecenter.ui.gtk3.app - INFO - setting up proxy 'None'
2015-06-27 20:53:27,737 - softwarecenter.region - WARNING - failed to use geoclue: 'org.freedesktop.Geoclue.Error.notAvailable: Geoclue master client has no usable Address providers'
```